# Android Popup Window is not showing in correct location

Tags: java, android, popupwindow

Hi I have a `FlowLayout` to display list of `textViews`. When I click a `textview` I have to show `PopWindow` below `textview`.But it's not showing in correct position.

```
public void showPopUpWindow(View view, int position) {
        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.layout_attributes_popup, null);
        FlowLayout flowLayout = linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.flow_layout);
        BubbleLayout bubbleLayout = linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.bubble_layout);
        prepareAttributes(flowLayout);
        PopupWindow mPopupWindow = BubbleHelper.create(this, linearLayout);
        mPopupWindow.setFocusable(true);
        mPopupWindow.update();
        if (mPopupWindow != null) {
            mPopupWindow.dismiss();
        }

        Rect rc = new Rect();
        view.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rc);
        int[] xy = new int[2];
        view.getLocationInWindow(xy);
        rc.offset(xy[0], xy[1]);

        //int[] location = new int[2];
        // view.getLocationInWindow(location);
        bubbleLayout.setArrowPosition(rc.left);
        //mPopupWindow.showAsDropDown(view, 0, 0);

        mPopupWindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, rc.left, rc.top);
    }
```

**OnClick Method:**

```
textView.setOnClickListener(view1 -> ((RichElementSelectionActivity) mContext).
                        showPopUpWindow(view1, mFlowLayout.indexOfChild((View) view1.getParent())));
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: where you are calling **showPopUpWindow** method

Comment: @Nilu textview i am calling in textview setOnClickListener method

Comment: please share that code with question

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. Also sharing a screenshot, that cannot be properly seen, is useless. Provide a screenshot with higher resolution.

Comment: @Nilu please check i updated

Comment: @ShanmugapriyanM pass the view of Your Textview like this **`TextView textView=new TextView(this);
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showPopUpWindow(view, mFlowLayout.indexOfChild((View) view1.getParent())));
            }
        });`**

Comment: @ShanmugapriyanM try this link
http://androidcodesnippetsblog.blogspot.nl/2013/09/android-custom-dialog-with-popup.html

Comment: @WaleedAsim i tried that link it's showing always top of the screen...

Comment: @ShanmugapriyanM did you solved it..?

Comment: @Nilu No.. please suggest some reference :(

Comment: @ShanmugapriyanM for test case try this `mPopupWindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, 0);`

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: it' showing in top

Comment: Please check screen shot

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue, so this is how I resolved it in `kotlin`

`view` is any view which you want to use as an anchor for popup-window

```
        val popupView: View = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_view_order_status, null)
        val popupWindow = PopupWindow(popupView,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        popupWindow.isFocusable = true
        popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable())
        val location = IntArray(2)
        view.getLocationOnScreen(location)
        popupWindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, location[0], location[1])
```